# I Need Help on a Set Up on my Video Editor on Blender

Tags: edit-mode, video

So what's happening is let's say like I take this video, I split it in half, I encode the one half, and then the other, but the other half, the second half, plays the same video from the first half but with the second half's audio. This has been happening to a game series I was doing with a friend. I use OBS Multiplatform as my game recorder and I use the High Profile as part of the recordings. So I was wondering if anybody could help with this.
[image]

Comment: Could you show the Video Sequence Editor of both halves?

Comment: Could you show some examples of what exactly happens and maybe upload your Blend-file for further examinations?

Comment: @Samoth Do you want my property set up to, I can also send you the actual two videos to if you want me to.

Comment: Use [blend exchange](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/738/2843) and just edit your answer for further details. You can upload the result (if licensing allows) to a video platform of your choice and link it here. Or show a screenshot of your VSE where the problem occurs (but that might still not be enough informations for a good answer)...

Comment: @Samoth, I thank you for the help, up on top you can see the .blend and I have these two videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9i8ulUouGo&feature=youtu.be - This is the first part of the video, this video strip works fine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-FAHP2AEx0&feature=youtu.be - Then here is the second part of the video, as you can tell it encoded the first part video frames, but with the second part video's audio.

Comment: @Samoth is there anything else you need?

Comment: @Carlo Can you help with this?

Comment: It's hard to say. From the file I wasn't able to get any clue. If possible, I would suggest to somehow upload the audio and video source file so we can examine the whole thing. Did you experienced similar behaviour with other input video too?

Comment: @Carlo My first video that I have made for my Youtube had the same problem, you can check it out here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2cdYfswIEw Except with this video it just skipped through the first episode and played the second one which is fine but weird. Did you see the two Youtube videos I posted showing the footage?